# Can ActiveRecord validations leak IMEMO objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

## Background

My team is attempting to track down a memory leak in our Rails 6.1 application. We used the technique described [here](https://medium.com/klaxit-techblog/tracking-a-ruby-memory-leak-in-2021-9eb56575f731) of taking three consecutive heap dumps and diffing them. We used [rbtrace](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace) to get the dumps and [rbheap](https://github.com/jimeh/rbheap) to do the diffing. We tried this several times with different intervals between the samples.

Versions:

- Rails 6.1.6.1
- Ruby 3.0.3

## Results

About 85% of the results in the diff look like the examples shown below. They are related to ActiveRecord's [numerically validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality), which we use in one of our models. [This](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.6.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/numericality.rb#L6-L10) is the validation's source code. The strange thing is these allocations are IMEMO objects, which according to this [article](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2018/01/23/reducing-memory-usage-in-ruby.html) store information about the compiled code.

### Validation in our model

```
validates :msrp, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: MAX_INT }, allow_nil: true
```

### Example IMEMO object allocations

```
{
  "address": "0x5632f3df7588",
  "type": "IMEMO",
  "class": "0x5632f654de48",
  "imemo_type": "callcache",
  "references": ["0x5632f654dbc8"],
  "file": "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.6.1/lib/active_record/validations/numericality.rb",
  "line": 10,
  "method": "validate_each",
  "generation": 9233,
  "memsize": 40,
  "flags": {
    "wb_protected": true,
    "old": true,
    "uncollectible": true,
    "marked": true
  }
}

{
  "address": "0x5632f3e0f070",
  "type": "IMEMO",
  "class": "0x5632f7dc23d0",
  "imemo_type": "callinfo",
  "file": "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.6.1/lib/active_record/validations/numericality.rb",
  "line": 10,
  "method": "validate_each",
  "generation": 6225,
  "memsize": 40,
  "flags": {
    "wb_protected": true,
    "old": true,
    "uncollectible": true,
    "marked": true
  }
}
```

## Questions

1. Has anyone witnessed similar behavior of memory leaks related to ActiveRecord validations?
2. Does anyone have a theory as to why so many IMEMO objects are allocated and leaked for the same line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a red herring. We removed the validation and still saw the same memory growth. A subsequent heap diff showed many more IMEMO objects from other methods.